# boost asio ; short read in udp; How to read each udp packet seperately

Tags: udp, boost-asio, multicast, asio

I am writing a program for receiving udp multicast packet. I came across short read. Is that applicable to udp? How do I ensure that I read one packet at a time? Is that possible?

My packet has a fixed size header followed by a variable length body.

[https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html#:~:text=When%20a%20short%20read%20or,write()%20and%20async_write()%20](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20short%20read%20or,write()%20and%20async_write()%20).

Answer (score 0):

> "I came across short read"

What does that mean? You mean you "heard about it"? Or received the error?

> Is that applicable to udp?

No. UDP is connectionless and DATAGRAM.

> How do I ensure that I read one packet at a time?

That's how UDP works.

> Is that possible?

Something else is not possible, although you can set flags that allow an incomplete datagram when the supplied buffer is too small to receive the complete datagram.

My packet has a fixed size header followed by a variable length body.

#### SUMMARY

The title of the page you linked was [Streams, Short Reads and Short Writes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20short%20read%20or,write()%20and%20async_write()%20). Your sockets are UDP, that is, not streams.

Comment: thanks. The questions could have been simplified to is short read applicable to udp?

Comment: ",... they commented, ironically drawing the question out even longer after it was already answered :)